# Static google maps dont work in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, subgurim-maps

i want to generate a map including large amount of information and lines on a web.
i try to apply static google maps in which it generates as image and it fast to load.i try to apply the following example but it doesnt desiply the map http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/ejemplos/ejemplo_999999_Static_Map.aspx .how can i make it work in asp.net web form?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="PlantDiseasesSystem.WebForm3" %>
<%@ Register assembly="GMaps" namespace="Subgurim.Controles" tagprefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<p>
    <br />
</p>
<cc1:StaticGMap ID="StaticGMap1" runat="server" />
<br />
<br />
<cc1:StaticGMap ID="StaticGMap2" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Have you got the  c# code that you are getting problems with?

Comment: i embeded google maps API 4 in asp.net .. and i work like the example i refer  to it ..but there ara no static google maps generated ..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413704/static-google-maps-dont-work-in-asp-net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is my work. I intended to open a google map in my own web site (not in google) to the user to move a marker on his adress (home, work and for another adresses). and then he/she is recording this marker place to the adress table on the server. when the other user opens his page they can see a "show on the map" link button. when they click the button explorer opens a google map (if you want you can do it in a div in your self page) and they can see the markers and descriptions about markers. I did not design lines in my project but you can ad them with the same way.

Another propertie of this code is the user -who adds his/her address- can find the adres with writing his/her address to a text box and uses google finding mechanism. So he/she can place the marker easiliy.

i used java and vb code. But the important section handled by javascript code becouse google subgrim is completaly java :)

Here is complete javascript code that mentioned.

```
var _id = "";
var _adres = "";
var _kull_adi = "";
var _lat;
var _lng;
var geocoder;
var map; 
var marker;
var koords = new Array();

window.onload = function () {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.42324,35.27587);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Move the marker to the address.',
        draggable: true
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (a) {
        _lat = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(8);
        _lng = a.latLng.lng().toFixed(8);
        $('#mapbilgileri_div').html("Enlem : " + _lat + "</br>Boylam : " + _lng);
    });
};

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            marker.setMap(null);
            map.setZoom(15);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: 'İşaretçiyi adresinizin üzerine getiriniz.',
                draggable: true
            });
            $('#mapbilgileri_div').html("Enlem : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(8) + "</br>Boylam : " + results[0].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(8));
            _lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(8);
            _lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(8);
            map.setCenter(marker.position);
            marker.setMap(map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (a) {
                _lat = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(8);
                _lng = a.latLng.lng().toFixed(8);
                $('#mapbilgileri_div').html("Enlem : " + _lat + "</br>Boylam : " + _lng);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Address couldn't find. Please be sure that you wrote it tuely!: " + status);
        }
    });
}

function set_guid(guid, adres,kull_adi,adres_decoded) {
    _id = guid;
    _adres = adres;
    _kull_adi = kull_adi;
    $('#address').val(adres_decoded);
    $('#adresbilgileri_div').html(_id + "</br>" + _adres);
    $('#mapbilgileri_div').html("Enlem : " + _lat + "</br>Boylam : " + _lng);
    codeAddress();
}

function koordinatekle() {
    if (_id.length > 3 && _lat != undefined && _lng != undefined && _adres.length > 3) {
        WebService.koordinatekle(_id, _lat, _lng, _kull_adi, geri_donus);
    } else {
        alert('Please select an address and coordinate from the map !')
    }
}

function geri_donus(result, eventArgs) {
    if (result = "1") {
        alert("coordinate added successfully.");
    } else {
        alert("Error!");
    }
    __doPostBack('', '');
}
```

there is some turkish words in code, think them just as names. And the web service code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function koordinatekle(ByVal _adres_tipi As String, ByVal _lat As Double, ByVal _lng As Double, ByVal _kull_adi As String) As String
        Try
            Dim _id As Integer = Val(_adres_tipi.Substring(_adres_tipi.IndexOf("-(ID:") + 5))
            If Left(_adres_tipi, 2) = "An" Then
                Dim sorgu = (From p In tablolar.genel_bilgilers Where p.kullanici_adi = _kull_adi Select p).First

                sorgu.lat = _lat
                sorgu.lon = _lng
                tablolar.SubmitChanges()
            End If
            If Left(_adres_tipi, 2) = "Ek" Then
                Dim sorgu = (From p In tablolar.free_texts Where p.id = _id Select p).First

                sorgu.lat = _lat
                sorgu.lon = _lng
                tablolar.SubmitChanges()
            End If
            Return 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Data.ToString
        End Try
    End Function
```

javascript code calls this service in order to record the selected marker place on a div element.

I used jquery dont forget because it eases the works so much. First it seems coplicated but very simple. Let me explain it.

**onload** function initialize the map. creates a **geocoder** for finding entered address. creates a map on "map" div element. creates a marker on this map and sets a listener for marker drag event.

**codeaddress** function tries to find the address which is entered by user. the important function of this:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {....
```

this function sends the adres data to google and try to gets the coordinates of adres.

another functions just sets the data and sends them to the server via a web services.

I hope this can help...

if it works don't forget vote me :) thanks.

**NOT:** I assume that you add the necessary google subgrim keys and necessary dll files (GMaps.dll) to your procet.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done this and it worked first time

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Website.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="Subgurim.Controles" Assembly="GMaps, Version=4.1.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=564d55b144e7aa5a" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <cc1:StaticGMap ID="StaticGMap1" runat="server" Language="en" format="png32" />
        <br />
        <cc1:StaticGMap ID="StaticGMap2" runat="server" Language="en" format="png32" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreLoad(e);

        LoadMap();
    }

    private void LoadMap()
    {
        GLatLng latLng = new GLatLng(41, -7);

        int colorEnumLength = 11;
        int sizeEnumLength = 3;
        double latStep = -1;
        double lngStep = 0.4;
        string msg = "Subgurim Google Maps";

        int iLat = 0;
        int iLng = 0;

        Random r = new Random();
        foreach (char c in msg)
        {
            if (c == ' ')
            {
                iLat++;
                continue;
            }

            GLatLng latlngAux = latLng + new GLatLng(latStep * iLat + r.NextDouble() * 0.4, lngStep * iLng);

            int randomColor = r.Next(colorEnumLength);
            StaticGMarker.ColorEnum color = (StaticGMarker.ColorEnum)randomColor;

            int randomSize = r.Next(2, sizeEnumLength);
            StaticGMarker.SizeEnum size = (StaticGMarker.SizeEnum)randomSize;

            StaticGMarker staticGMarker = new StaticGMarker(latlngAux, size, color, c);
            StaticGMap1.addStaticGMarker(staticGMarker);

            iLng++;
        }

        StaticPath path = new StaticPath();
        path.colorNet = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 80);
        path.weight = 5;
        path.alpha = 150;

        path.points.Add(new GLatLng(41, -5));
        path.points.Add(new GLatLng(41, -4));
        path.points.Add(new GLatLng(40, -4));
        path.points.Add(new GLatLng(39, -2));

        StaticGMap1.addStaticPath(path);

        StaticGMap2.setCenter(new GLatLng("Valencia, Spain"));
        GLatLng paris = new GLatLng("Paris");
        GLatLng athens = new GLatLng();
        athens.optionalStringValue = "athens";

        StaticGMap2.addStaticGMarker(new StaticGMarker(paris, new StaticGIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/sunny.png")));
        StaticGMap2.addStaticGMarker(new StaticGMarker(athens, new StaticGIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/sunny.png", true)));

        StaticPath path2 = new StaticPath();
        path2.fillColorNet = Color.Brown;
        path2.colorNet = Color.ForestGreen;
        path2.weight = 2;
        path2.alpha = 150;
        path2.points.Add(new GLatLng("Berlin"));
        path2.points.Add(new GLatLng("Rome"));
        path2.points.Add(new GLatLng("Morocco"));
        StaticGMap2.Add(path2);
    }
}
```

Did you reference* the GMap.dll?

Did you compile the application?

*Update

**EDIT**

I said register, I meant reference. What I would do is place the GMap.dll into a folder called Libs in your solution root (and not in the bin folder) and then  in Visual Studio right click on your project and select 'Add Reference...', then browse to the .dll file in the Libs folder, selected it, click ok a few times. Now build you solution (press the combination Ctrl + Shift + B)

We really need to see the code from your page though, if you've made a small mistake in copying it, it could break it. Otherwise it's like taking your car to be fixed but not letting the mechanic look under the hood!

Comment: No,idont register any thing ,i just download it from subgurim ..and embed it....if i need to register it ..please can you tell me how to do it .

Comment: i dont have any public key ..the difference in my code is  :        <%@ Register assembly="GMaps" namespace="Subgurim.Controles" tagprefix="cc1" %>                                                                 but in your code :   <%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="Subgurim.Controles" Assembly="GMaps, Version=4.1.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=564d55b144e7aa5a" %>

Comment: does this mean that i dont add it in right way ..or becuase i dont have public key token....how can i get this key ...i ask many question becuase i new in google maps applications